# sql left join array to id

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find a solution to have multiple joins where the DB schema looks like that;

```
table a
array ["1","2","3"]

table b
id 1
id 2
```

i will need to left join each id to the array.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_b LEFT JOIN tbl_a ON tbl_b.id=tbl_a.array
```

how can this be done?

Comment: How can a table have a field as array (Assuming field type is a string and you are adding data in the format of array.)

Comment: its a text field so array looks like ["1","2","3"]

Comment: I am using mysql DB